LVM - Couldn't find device with uuid 'xxx-xxx-xx-xx'
This is a VMware VM recovered by Veeam B&R, after that I try to boot the VM but appears some errors relating to missing PVs. This the thing:
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid TAa5ei-oJrz-t1Fs-a6dH-OCXf-cx23-JxNz8C.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid THwbYj-NsSV-8J0z-yCnD-E0Zg-hvss-LfGXN2.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid qYrust-yeOX-JUeb-sr2Y-mlqZ-VIeH-FRYP7r.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid EcvYcl-eDSC-gqVy-AVSe-EWe4-RN5J-Wc9YVQ.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 44aGUQ-W8aD-XkGx-99hS-WHVZ-Lxjt-Tv5FeW.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid fh7OnQ-QaQ1-EqQr-LMwl-WGCk-1NiL-bqudMc.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 0KsuZk-2dt8-RvBo-zmat-6vwh-iZev-iN5cIF.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid SIOoym-McVL-ZPec-XC8w-ZUy9-relQ-YevLSV.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 1VKrRt-X1er-CIPW-rfBR-GxGQ-AyDX-uQNoeq.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid jZWzHw-rIbD-s0uz-DEAn-DSm6-IMlq-pv46iJ.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid r6zuEy-uU2x-SwSq-G9Vt-KOZa-FUQQ-clNhIS.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid TNhC6d-HAu3-XJTy-vLvr-g4Ik-ZeE1-2YLghx.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid ZOCVnd-0xXl-0G2C-T3ql-5Ijv-v23T-5tQpCK.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid hnWk0G-aHUw-cT8f-OSzK-sYn9-s6lL-4u5fbf.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid c8K3rc-V4tv-TR3n-lY7j-ZjGg-LjFP-VMHx4e.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid eETvWd-F3Kd-Pu10-dUon-fnIr-DLux-pvADc9.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sda3 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sda5 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sdi1 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sdo1 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sdp in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV TAa5ei-oJrz-t1Fs-a6dH-OCXf-cx23-JxNz8C (last written to /dev/sdb1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV THwbYj-NsSV-8J0z-yCnD-E0Zg-hvss-LfGXN2 (last written to /dev/sdc1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV qYrust-yeOX-JUeb-sr2Y-mlqZ-VIeH-FRYP7r (last written to /dev/sdd1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV EcvYcl-eDSC-gqVy-AVSe-EWe4-RN5J-Wc9YVQ (last written to /dev/sdf1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV 44aGUQ-W8aD-XkGx-99hS-WHVZ-Lxjt-Tv5FeW (last written to /dev/sde1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV fh7OnQ-QaQ1-EqQr-LMwl-WGCk-1NiL-bqudMc (last written to /dev/sdh1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV 0KsuZk-2dt8-RvBo-zmat-6vwh-iZev-iN5cIF (last written to /dev/sdi1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV SIOoym-McVL-ZPec-XC8w-ZUy9-relQ-YevLSV (last written to /dev/sdj1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV 1VKrRt-X1er-CIPW-rfBR-GxGQ-AyDX-uQNoeq (last written to /dev/sdk).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV jZWzHw-rIbD-s0uz-DEAn-DSm6-IMlq-pv46iJ (last written to /dev/sdl).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV r6zuEy-uU2x-SwSq-G9Vt-KOZa-FUQQ-clNhIS (last written to /dev/sdo1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV TNhC6d-HAu3-XJTy-vLvr-g4Ik-ZeE1-2YLghx (last written to /dev/sdp1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV ZOCVnd-0xXl-0G2C-T3ql-5Ijv-v23T-5tQpCK (last written to /dev/sdq).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV hnWk0G-aHUw-cT8f-OSzK-sYn9-s6lL-4u5fbf (last written to /dev/sdr).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV c8K3rc-V4tv-TR3n-lY7j-ZjGg-LjFP-VMHx4e (last written to /dev/sds1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV eETvWd-F3Kd-Pu10-dUon-fnIr-DLux-pvADc9 (last written to /dev/sdt1).

The content of /etc/lvm/VolGroup00_00000-815974025.vg is:
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.03.21(2) (2023-04-21): Wed Jul 31 15:00:31 2024

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *before* executing 'vgs --noheadings --nosuffix --nameprefixes --unquoted --units=b -o name,uuid,size,free,extent_size,extent_count,free_count,pv_count '--config= log {level=7 file=/tmp/lvm.log syslog=0}' --devices=/dev/sda3'"

creation_host = "localhost.localdomain" # Linux localhost.localdomain 5.14.0-362.8.1.el9_3.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 8 17:36:32 UTC 2023 x86_64
creation_time = 1722438031  # Wed Jul 31 15:00:31 2024

VolGroup00 {
    id = "Qdx1Y7-LbwR-OJxa-2t87-A7mA-LxDd-fc3INj"
    seqno = 56
    format = "lvm2"         # informational
    status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
    flags = []
    extent_size = 65536     # 32 Megabytes
    max_lv = 0
    max_pv = 0
    metadata_copies = 0

    physical_volumes {

        pv0 {
            id = "iIIMZD-KJt0-3eKB-k3qc-SDlB-D9wN-Tu2cDB"
            device = "/dev/sda3"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = []
            dev_size = 620542371    # 295.898 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 9468 # 295.875 Gigabytes
        }

        pv1 {
            id = "TAa5ei-oJrz-t1Fs-a6dH-OCXf-cx23-JxNz8C"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 104856192    # 49.9993 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv2 {
            id = "iHQ0O7-2Ebt-1ua1-kIJw-Usgu-cy2g-fOcpYs"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 104856192    # 49.9993 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv3 {
            id = "THwbYj-NsSV-8J0z-yCnD-E0Zg-hvss-LfGXN2"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 524280828    # 249.997 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 7999 # 249.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv4 {
            id = "qYrust-yeOX-JUeb-sr2Y-mlqZ-VIeH-FRYP7r"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 524280828    # 249.997 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 7999 # 249.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv5 {
            id = "EcvYcl-eDSC-gqVy-AVSe-EWe4-RN5J-Wc9YVQ"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 629137467    # 299.996 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 9599 # 299.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv6 {
            id = "44aGUQ-W8aD-XkGx-99hS-WHVZ-Lxjt-Tv5FeW"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv7 {
            id = "VPI6vR-2fHA-nbQa-UAkx-O6mQ-HVmb-4M8omx"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 115330572    # 54.9939 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 1759 # 54.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv8 {
            id = "fh7OnQ-QaQ1-EqQr-LMwl-WGCk-1NiL-bqudMc"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 419424957    # 199.997 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 6399 # 199.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv9 {
            id = "0KsuZk-2dt8-RvBo-zmat-6vwh-iZev-iN5cIF"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 1048562487   # 499.994 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv10 {
            id = "SIOoym-McVL-ZPec-XC8w-ZUy9-relQ-YevLSV"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 1048562487   # 499.994 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv11 {
            id = "1VKrRt-X1er-CIPW-rfBR-GxGQ-AyDX-uQNoeq"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv12 {
            id = "jZWzHw-rIbD-s0uz-DEAn-DSm6-IMlq-pv46iJ"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv13 {
            id = "c7uAOZ-FA93-qgy4-RVXx-7moC-pYwK-QTkIiw"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv14 {
            id = "2nYU3z-U6hp-Hm71-HhbP-IlS0-Onis-4opu4S"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 419430400    # 200 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 6399 # 199.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv15 {
            id = "r6zuEy-uU2x-SwSq-G9Vt-KOZa-FUQQ-clNhIS"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv16 {
            id = "TNhC6d-HAu3-XJTy-vLvr-g4Ik-ZeE1-2YLghx"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv17 {
            id = "ZOCVnd-0xXl-0G2C-T3ql-5Ijv-v23T-5tQpCK"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv18 {
            id = "hnWk0G-aHUw-cT8f-OSzK-sYn9-s6lL-4u5fbf"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv19 {
            id = "c8K3rc-V4tv-TR3n-lY7j-ZjGg-LjFP-VMHx4e"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv20 {
            id = "eETvWd-F3Kd-Pu10-dUon-fnIr-DLux-pvADc9"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 1048562487   # 499.994 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes
        }
    }

    logical_volumes {

        root {
            id = "fj0MoK-hmUH-viTe-QaD1-VYA0-vVBU-Eu8xzF"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            segment_count = 5

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 9468 # 295.875 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 0
                ]
            }
            segment2 {
                start_extent = 9468
                extent_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv1", 0
                ]
            }
            segment3 {
                start_extent = 11067
                extent_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv2", 0
                ]
            }
            segment4 {
                start_extent = 12666
                extent_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv3", 0
                ]
            }
            segment5 {
                start_extent = 14265
                extent_count = 1569 # 49.0312 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv4", 0
                ]
            }
        }

        alfresco {
            id = "pRzFfr-ej3P-fZ7l-tHSQ-sE4b-qPBG-LkxZBP"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            segment_count = 20

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 9599 # 299.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv5", 0
                ]
            }
            segment2 {
                start_extent = 9599
                extent_count = 30   # 960 Megabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv4", 1569
                ]
            }
            segment3 {
                start_extent = 9629
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv6", 0
                ]
            }
            segment4 {
                start_extent = 12828
                extent_count = 1759 # 54.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv7", 0
                ]
            }
            segment5 {
                start_extent = 14587
                extent_count = 6399 # 199.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv8", 0
                ]
            }
            segment6 {
                start_extent = 20986
                extent_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv9", 0
                ]
            }
            segment7 {
                start_extent = 36985
                extent_count = 6400 # 200 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv3", 1599
                ]
            }
            segment8 {
                start_extent = 43385
                extent_count = 6400 # 200 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv4", 1599
                ]
            }
            segment9 {
                start_extent = 49785
                extent_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv10", 0
                ]
            }
            segment10 {
                start_extent = 65784
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv11", 0
                ]
            }
            segment11 {
                start_extent = 68983
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv12", 0
                ]
            }
            segment12 {
                start_extent = 72182
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv13", 0
                ]
            }
            segment13 {
                start_extent = 75381
                extent_count = 6368 # 199 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv14", 0
                ]
            }
            segment14 {
                start_extent = 81749
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv15", 0
                ]
            }
            segment15 {
                start_extent = 84948
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv16", 0
                ]
            }
            segment16 {
                start_extent = 88147
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv17", 0
                ]
            }
            segment17 {
                start_extent = 91346
                extent_count = 31   # 992 Megabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv14", 6368
                ]
            }
            segment18 {
                start_extent = 91377
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv18", 0
                ]
            }
            segment19 {
                start_extent = 94576
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv19", 0
                ]
            }
            segment20 {
                start_extent = 97775
                extent_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv20", 0
                ]
            }
        }
    }

}

And the fdisk shows this:
Disk /dev/sda: 350 GiB, 375809638400 bytes, 734003200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d8061

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63    208844    208782 101.9M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          208845   8594774   8385930     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         8594775 629137529 620542755 295.9G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda4       629137530 733993784 104856255    50G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       629137593 733993784 104856192    50G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 250 GiB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf: 250 GiB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdg: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdh: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdi: 55 GiB, 59055800320 bytes, 115343360 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdi1          63 115330634 115330572  55G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdj: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdk: 500 GiB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdl: 500 GiB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdm: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdn: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdo: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdo1          63 209712509 209712447  100G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdp: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdq: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I know this is a crappy mess, but I don't know that to do to recover every disk/partition to PV. Can you help me?

This seems to be an issue… with your VM setup and/or its recovery, and not something you can salvage from within the VM. If metadata / uuid is missing from these PV then most likely, everything else is missing too - can you confirm there is non-zero data on them at all? Recovering a VM with dozen virtual drives is probably a tall order for any recovery software… what happened anyway?

"This is a VMware VM recovered by Veeam B&R" - Veeam support is usually pretty good, and least in my experience. And the company understands Linux-based systems. If you get nowhere useful here - or even if you do - I'd strongly recommend you use the support that (I assume) you're paying for and ask them to help with what appears to be a failed recovery
